# Is this possible to make this code randomize the images for the slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

Here i have some code which is my slideshow and what i am wondering is whether you can randomize the images so it doesn't start on the same image when you refresh the page.

Please provide me with useful info and if you wish to show me feel free.

THNAKS GUYS! :)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JQuery Cycle Plugin Sample</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../screen.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js2/jquery-1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js2/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myslides').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            speed: 2000,
            timeout: 2000
        });
    }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myslides"> 
    <img src="../images/capitol.jpg" />
    <img src="../images/flowers.jpg" />
    <img src="../images/countryscene.jpg" />
    <img src="../images/heartkush.jpg"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If possible could you also let me know in how to improve the question in order to get this across to people better if its need to. :)

Comment: I've just added the correct answer to this question...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may want to hold image urls in a variable (or retrieve them from your `div` and clear the `div` afterwards), say

```
var images = ['x.jpg', 'y.jpg', 'z.jpg'];
```

(or even better - do some preloading). Then do a random sort

```
function randomOrd(a,b)
{
   return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5);
}
images.sort(randomOrd);
```

then dynamically add images

```
for (var i in images)
{
   $('#myslides').append('<img src="'+images[i]+'" />');
}
```

and then do the slideshow. The final script may look like this:

```
<script>
    function randOrd(a,b)
    {
        return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5);
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var images = [];
        /* retrieve images */
        $('div#myslides img').each(function(){
            images.push($(this));
        });
        /* clear the div */
        $('div#myslides').empty();
        /* do the random sort of images */
        images.sort(randOrd);
        /* append to the div sorted images */
        for (var i in images)
        {
            $('div#myslides').append(images[i]);
        }
        /* do the slideshow */
        $('#myslides').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            speed: 2000,
            timeout: 2000
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Nothing at all. The script at the bottom of my post will do everything for you. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#myslides img").each(function() { 
      if (Math.random() >= 0.5) { $("#myslides").append($(this)); } 
});
```

Comment: This code will duplicate images. And furthermore it won't change the starting list of images.

Comment: You're wrong. Append doesn't duplicate items. And it will indeed change the order of the images. Try it out.

Comment: You're right. Append does not duplicate items. But in that case this code does nothing (tried a minute ago). And how could it? You try to append elements which already are in div?

Comment: By using append on an element already in the div, it moves the element to the last position. Works just dandy for me, though it does seem to have a bias to the natural order of things (elements appear unchanged about one time out of five), which can be adjusted away by changing the 0.5 up there, i suspect.

Comment: This is interesting. I didn't know about that (although this behaviour seems to be very strange). But still it didn't work even once for me (with 0.5 probability, tried around 100 times :D). Under Chrome.

Comment: Make sure you run it after the image tags have been loaded, so either in the footer of your page or in document.ready. I don't have chrome on this computer, but it works good for me in FF and IE. Always nice to learn new things.

Answer (score -1):

This is just one of the many [options](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html) that jQuery cycle has.

Add `random: true` to the options like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myslides').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 2000,
        timeout: 2000,
        random: true
    });
});
```